# The ratio $a:b:c$ of the sides of a triangle with angles $\alpha=120^\circ$ and $\beta=30^\circ$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

We have just studied the law of sines. I am trying to find the ratio $a:b:c$ of the sides of a triangle with angles $\alpha=120^\circ$ and $\beta=30^\circ.$

We can calculate the third angle of the triangle: $\gamma=180^\circ-\alpha-\beta=30^\circ.$ So the triangle is isosceles. The law of sines gives us $$a:b:c=\sin\alpha:\sin\beta:\sin\gamma=$$ $$=\sin120^\circ:\sin30^\circ:\sin30^\circ=\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}:\dfrac12:\dfrac12=\left(\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}\cdot2\right):\dfrac{1}{2}=\text{...}=2\sqrt3.$$ That can't be it! Where am I wrong?

Comment: I don't understand. Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: We don't understand. You found $\sqrt{3}:1:1$. What're you writing after it, in your post?

Comment: See my comment under Parcly's answer.

Comment: $\sqrt{3}/2:1/2:1/2 = \sqrt{3}:1:1$ on doubling each.

Comment: @cosmo5, thank you! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @nicoledobreva: You seem to be taking the ratio indicator "$:$" as a division operator. This arguably isn't "wrong" in a two-term ratio (we often conflate $a:b$ and $\frac{a}{b}$), but it doesn't make sense in a multi-term one. So, once you have $a:b:c$, all you can do is simplify by multiplying- or dividing-through by a common (non-zero) value.

Comment: @Blue, thank you! A really nice explanation. I really thought that the ratio indicator as you pointed is the same as the division operator. By "multiplying- or dividing-through by a common value" you mean I can multiply (or divide) each of the terms by a fixed number, right?

Comment: @nicoledobreva: *"By "multiplying- or dividing-through by a common value" you mean I can multiply (or divide) each of the terms by a fixed number, right?"* Right. Like @ cosmo5 did in getting from your answer to $\sqrt3:1:1$ by "doubling each".

Answer (score 2):

You are correct; $a:b:c=\sqrt3:1:1$.

Comment: But I got that $a:b:c=2\sqrt3$. How do we conclude $a:b:c=\sqrt3:1:1$?

Comment: How are you turning a ratio of $3$ numbers into a single number?

Comment: @nicoledobreva You have written something that is not even wrong.

Comment: @nicoledobreva $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}:\frac{1}{2}:\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\times2:\frac{1}{2}\times2:\frac{1}{2}\times2=\sqrt{3}:1:1$

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help.